# Migrating to Oracle 12c from previous version: Do I use a multitenant container database (CDB) or non-CDB database

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am currently attempting to add Oracle 12c support for our very large project that has been in development for many years.  We are currently running on Oracle 10g.

If I run the script I use in 10g to create our database objects using 12c I get an ORA-65096 error when I attempt to create the user, [which is described here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_65096_create_user_12c_without_c_prefix.htm).

If I use the following fix I can create the user and my database schema using the scripts that are used for 10g:

```
alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;
```

However, when the application executes I'm getting the following permissions error:

```
EJB Invocation failed on component CommonDaoEJB for method public abstract java.lang.String com.mycompany.myappserver.dao.remote.CommonDao.getSchemaVersion(java.lang.String): javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:166) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:230) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.processInvocation(EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.java:80) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.AuthorizationInterceptor.processInvocation(AuthorizationInterceptor.java:106) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:76) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:302) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.access$200(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:64) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler$1.run(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:196) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1361) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:816) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:770) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.find(AbstractEntityManager.java:193) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at com.mycompany.myappserver.ejb.CommonDaoBean.getSystemContextProperty(CommonDaoBean.java:565) [myappserverejb.jar:]
    at com.mycompany.myappserver.ejb.CommonDaoBean.getSchemaVersion(CommonDaoBean.java:67) [myappserverejb.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:36) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:228) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1978) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2058) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3697) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:439) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:420) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:204) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:251) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:148) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:954) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:870) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:863) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:795) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:91) [ojdbc6-11.1.0.7.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133) [ojdbc6-11.1.0.7.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:206) [ojdbc6-11.1.0.7.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455) [ojdbc6-11.1.0.7.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:413) [ojdbc6-11.1.0.7.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:1034) [ojdbc6-11.1.0.7.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:194) [ojdbc6-11.1.0.7.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:791) [ojdbc6-11.1.0.7.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:866) [ojdbc6-11.1.0.7.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1186) [ojdbc6-11.1.0.7.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3387) [ojdbc6-11.1.0.7.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3431) [ojdbc6-11.1.0.7.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491) [ojdbc6-11.1.0.7.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.7.0-Production"]
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:462)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    ... 72 more
```

I'm thinking this is related to the user not being associated with a CDB and therefore not having privileges to the objects in the schema.

Before I can start trying to fix this I need to determine if the user needs to be created as a CDB user or a non-CDB user.  Also if the user is a CDB user how do I create the CDB that the user should be associated with?

Some additional information.

- All of the database interaction for the creation of the database objects is through jdbc.
- The application connects through JBoss 7.1.1-final using hibernate with the dialect set to 10g as a JVM arg when JBoss is started like this: Dhibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
- The following statements are executed to create the database objects:

```
alter session set \"_ORACLE_SCRIPT\"=true

create tablespace myapp4 datafile 'myapp4.dbf' size 100M reuse
  autoextend on next 500M maxsize 25000M

create user myapp4 identified by myapp4

grant all privileges to myapp4

alter user myapp4 quota unlimited on myapp4
```

Following these steps a script is run that creates the table etc. in the `myapp4` schema.

Comment: What exactly have you created - just a root container? A root and a seed, or a root and a PDB? A standalone database? What are you connecting to when you run the schema creation script and from your application?

Comment: Added as an edit to the original question.

Comment: How did you create the 12c database though?

Comment: Maybe that's the part that needs to occur but isn't?  Doesn't the following statement create the database: `create user myapp4 identified by myapp4`.  After this statement is executed a different process is run.  This process connects as the myapp4 user and runs a series of ddl statements like: create table foo_bar (id number(20)).

Comment: That creates a *schema*, not a database. You are connecting to the existing database as a privileged user - SYS, or someone else who can create users  - to run your script. I suspect you're doing that connection to the root container and then your application is connecting to a PDB, but without knowing what `create database` and/or `create pluggable database` commands you used, and the connection strings you are using for both steps, I can only guess.

Comment: As far as I know there is no create database statement that is currently being executed.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the underlying issue here was actually caused by using the incorrect jdbc driver jar.

This problem was fixed by adding the odbc7.jar file that came with the installed product (installed here by default 
\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib) and then setting the hibernate dialect by adding the following jvm parameter to the jboss startup script:

-Dhibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

After making these changes the legacy 10g application is up and running and ready for testing in 12c.

So the answer to the specific question asked here is: Neither, I was able to get my application including the scripts used to create the 10g schema to work in 12c "as-is" once I got everything configured correctly.